# Flatten dictionaries of list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Using python 2.6.5, I am trying to flatten the all the lists that are attach to each dictionary key and put them as one list if possible as a one unique set. I tried with two different functions and just not sure what I need to do.

The problem I'm having is that it's not returning a list of values but list of keys.

For example:

```
dict = {'alpha': [[], ['dg1']],
        'beta': [[], ['dg2'], ['dg3'], ['dg4'], ['dg1']],
        'charlie': [[], ['dg1']],
        'delta': [[], ['dg4']]}

new_list = flatten(dict)
```

results in `[alpha,beta,charile,delta]`, but I want is `[dg1,dg2,dg3,dg4]`.

What I havve tried:

```
def flatten(a):
    b = []
    for c in a:
        if isinstance(c, list) and any(isinstance(i, list) for i in c):
            b.extend(flatten(c))
        else:
            b.append(c)
    return b

def flatten_list(lst):
    """
    Utility to flatten a list of list.
    If outer list is not list or None, it returns the original object.
    It will return None for None.
    """
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return lst
    return sum(([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else flatten_list(x)
                    for x in lst), [])
```

Comment: Don't call `sum` on lists. It only works by accident, because the author of `sum` couldn't figure out a good way to make it not work. It's also inefficient.

Comment: Also, please give us a complete example—give us a list that each of the two functions fails on.

Comment: The example list I gave fails on both.

Comment: The [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library has a recipe: search for **flatten** on that page.

Comment: You didn't give an example list, you gave an example dict with four lists in it, and `flatten_list` works on all four of them. (Again, you shouldn't use `flatten_list` anyway. But if you're claiming it doesn't work, you have to give us an example where it actually doesn't work.)

Comment: From your edit: You wrote a function that flattens any list or iterable. That function is buggy, as explained in my answer, but let's ignore that. You then called that function on a dict. A dict is just an iterable of its keys. That's why you need a loop over the dictionary's items, as is also explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the logic in this part of the code:

```
if isinstance(c, list) and any(isinstance(i, list) for i in c):
    b.extend(flatten(c))
else:
    b.append(c)
```

If `c` is a list without any lists inside, you're just going to `append` it onto `b`, instead of `extending`. So, if `b = [0]` and `c = [1, 2]`, you'll end up with `b = [0, [1, 2]]`.

You need to *always* extend if `c` is a list. So, you can do this:

```
if isinstance(c, list):
    if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in c):
        b.extend(flatten(c))
    else:
        b.extend(c)
else:
    b.append(c)
```

This will work. But think about what happens if you call `flatten` on an already-flat list, and you should be able to simplify this further.

---

Meanwhile, if you don't know how to flatten each value in a dict, you can do it with an explicit loop:

```
d = {'alpha': [[], ['dg1']], 'beta': [[], ['dg2'], ['dg3'], ['dg4'], ['dg1']], 'charlie': [[], ['dg1']], 'delta': [[], ['dg4']]}
new_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    new_d[k] = flatten(v)
```

I've used `d.items()` there. In Python 2.x, that gives you a new list, with all the key-value pairs for the dictionary. If the dictionary is huge, making that list just to loop over it can be wasteful, so you may want to use `d.iteritems()` instead, which gives you a lazy iterator instead of a list.

---

If you know what comprehensions are, you should recognize this pattern of "create an empty collection, loop, add to the collection" as a paradigm case for converting to a comprehension:

```
new_d = {k: flatten(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Unfortunately, dictionary comprehensions weren't added until 2.7. But you can get the same effect with the `dict` function and a generator expression:

```
new_d = dict((k, flatten(v)) for k, v in d.items())
```

Not quite as readable, but it has the same effect, and it works back to 2.4.

Comment: I fail to mention i'm using 2.6.5 not python 3. I can't use items(). Is there alterative for comprehension and list in python 2.6.5

Comment: @user3590149: You definitely can use `.items()` in 2.6. You might want to use `.iteritems()` instead; I'll edit to explain. You can't use a dict comprehension, but I'll show you another alternative—or, of course, you can just use the explicit `for` loop directly above that.

Comment: This doesn't work what happened is that I'm only getting a list of keys.

Comment: @user3590149: Yes, it does work. If you've copied something wrong, I can't debug it by guessing at what you might have copied. But there's no way that this could possibly give you a list.

Comment: @user3590149: You can see it working [at this online repl.it session](http://repl.it/3o5).

Comment: O sorry I wasn't following on how you were setting everything up. I figure that out. I was wondering, is ther performance benefits from list comprehension or is just for readablity? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3590149: Comprehensions are usually a little faster, but you're talking best-case speedup of 20-40%, which rarely makes a difference. Readability is the main benefit, but there are others. For example, you can use a comprehension in an expression (like as the argument to a function call). Also, avoiding repetition and boilerplate means fewer places to make a stupid typo, and if you make as many of those as me, that's always a nice win.